# Get All User Data in jhipster (for relationship management)

Tags: jhipster

I want to get the email adresses from all users of the user entity. (frontend - angular) But i get a 500 error ( -> no admin). is there a workaround.

Comment: Please edit your question to add missing details like the logs of the error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.